# is it possible to add a picture from the internet to a fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, picasso

My layout called `circleview` has this snippet of code in it

```
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/stephelm"
    android:id="@+id/circleview"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
     />
```

this displays the picture I want when i inflate the fragment.

What I want to do is load a picture from facebook into this fragment.

I can load a photo  from facebook via `Picasso`

`Picasso.with(this).load("https://graph.facebook.com/" + "name.lastname" + "/picture?type=large").into(imageView);`

Is there a way to do this in XML?

Answer (score 0):

You can use com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView. This comes from the official android library.